# What happens when I call a function without assigning its returned value to a variable?

Tags: c++

Say I have the following function:

```
int foo()
{
    return 1234;
}
```

What is the effect of calling this function without assigning its returned value to any variable:

```
foo();
```

Also what is the effect of using an operator without assigning its returned value to any variable:

```
1 + 2 + 3;
```

Comment: There is _no_ effect. By definition. What "effect" did you expect??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ an expression is a valid statement; the computed value is simply discarded.

Some compilers are smart enough to inform you with a warning if the code looks strange; for example having:

```
foo(1,2,3);
```

can make sense (calls the function that probably has side effects) but code like

```
x < 3;
```

is not useful because it has no defined side effect and the value is discarded.

In g++ there also some library functions that despite having side effects are marked specifically so that ignoring the return value raises a warning (like `fread`) because it's a sign of a bug waiting to bite.

There are also very common cases in which ignoring the result of a function is done frequently (like `printf`) and in which expressions that return a value are used only for the side effect (like `std::cout << "Hello";`).

If you want to enforce at run time that the result of a function has not been silently ignored there is a trick that sometimes can be used:

```
template<typename T>
struct must_check {
    T x;
    bool checked;
    must_check(const T& x) : x(x), checked(false) {}
    operator T () { checked = true; return x; }
    ~must_check() {
        if (!checked)
          throw std::runtime_error("Result value has not been checked");
    }
};
```

Now instead of writing

```
int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

just write

```
must_check<int> square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

Then code like

```
square(12);
```

will throw an exception at runtime, while

```
int result = square(12);
```

will work fine.

This is possible but is not a really good idea however, because throwing an exception in a destructor is a really bad behavior that most often results in terminating a program abnormally (the reason is that sometimes destructors are called automatically because of an exception, throwing **another** exception during that phase is a lethal move).

## UPDATE

C++17 introduced an annotation so that discarded return values that are suspicious can emit a warning at compile time. For example the code

```
[[nodiscard]] double square(double x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

will trigger a warning at compile time if the return value is not used.

Comment: an extremly common case would be `cout << "Hello";` which returns an `ostream` value, but we most often ignore it. As will `printf("Hello");` [it returns the number of characters actually printed - but most people completely ignore the return value of printf. Hence the compiler is told not  to issue a warning for these things.

Answer (score 1):

The operation or function will be evaluated and will continue running. Depending on your compiler, you may see a warning but it will otherwise continue running without issue.

Answer (score 1):

At a low level,when a function returns value,this value is copied into eax(on 32-bit machine)  or rax(64-bit machine) register,then caller function uses eax or rax register to read returned data.
In this case caller function just doesn't read eax/rax registers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not obliged to do anything with a function's returned value in C++. You can call function and simply ignore the returned value. Operator is also function, thus you can call it, then expression will be evaluated and again - result may be just forgotten.