# Why is the return type of the function not consistent with the actual sentence?

Tags: c++, function, return-type

In the program, it has:

```
EnergyFunctional* ef;
ef->insertFrame(fh, &Hcalib);
```

The function is defined as follows:

```
EFFrame* EnergyFunctional::insertFrame(FrameHessian* fh, CalibHessian* Hcalib)
{
    EFFrame* eff = new EFFrame(fh);
    eff->idx = frames.size();
    frames.push_back(eff);

    nFrames++;
    fh->efFrame = eff;

    assert(HM.cols() == 8*nFrames+CPARS-8); ///  CPARS = 4
    bM.conservativeResize(8*nFrames+CPARS);
    HM.conservativeResize(8*nFrames+CPARS,8*nFrames+CPARS);
    bM.tail<8>().setZero();
    HM.rightCols<8>().setZero();
    HM.bottomRows<8>().setZero();

    EFIndicesValid = false;
    EFAdjointsValid=false;
    EFDeltaValid=false;

    setAdjointsF(Hcalib);
    makeIDX();


    for(EFFrame* fh2 : frames)
    {
        connectivityMap[(((uint64_t)eff->frameID) << 32) + ((uint64_t)fh2->frameID)] = Eigen::Vector2i(0,0); /// move left 32 bits
        if(fh2 != eff)
            connectivityMap[(((uint64_t)fh2->frameID) << 32) + ((uint64_t)eff->frameID)] = Eigen::Vector2i(0,0);  /// index is totally 64 bits, front 32 bits for each frame, rear 32 bits for current frame
    }

    return eff;
}
```

It seems like the return type should be void so that it can be consistent with last sentence...

I also checked if there is other same name "inserFrame" functions, but there is not.

This program can be compiled successfully, but why can it be no problem?

Comment: `insertFrame` does indeed return a pointer, but in this snippet they did not assign the pointer back to anything `ef->insertFrame(fh, &Hcalib);` That is [completely legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142017/what-happens-when-i-call-a-function-without-assigning-its-returned-value-to-a-va) (although probably frowned upon). In this case, they might be calling the function for it's side effects, not it's return value.

Comment: To my knowledge, neither C++ nor C has ever required the return value from a function to be caught in a variable or otherwise used. Nor does any compiler warn about unused return values at any warning level I've used.

Comment: @FredLarson Regarding your last statement, GCC has [`-Wunused-result`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and Visual Studio has [C6031](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81s4zzd4.aspx)

Comment: @CoryKramer: And I've never used that specific warning directive. No such warning is included in gcc/g++ `-Wall`, and I doubt any is included in MSVC's equivalent. My point being, if you want that warning you have to ask specifically for it.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Actually, it appears that directive applies only to functions declared with the `warn_unused_result` attribute. Am I correct?

Comment: @FredLarson Yes I think that is right, I think that particular warning is prone to a lot of false positives, particularly with overloaded operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type specified by the function is `EFFrame*`, which is a pointer to an `EFFrame` object. The value being returned by the function is `eff`, which is a `EFFrame*` type pointer as well. So there shouldn't be any confusion.

You would only use a `void` return type in the function declaration if you are not returning a value. However, as shown in the last line, this function is clearly trying to return a pointer to a `EFFrame` object.

However, even in functions that have a clearly defined return type, it may not be necessary to use that value. Hence it is technically legal to just call the function and not store the return value into a variable. Hence, even though `ef->insertFrame(fh, &Hcalib);` is calling the function and returning a `EFFrame*` pointer, it just isn't being stored.